# Adding product attributes to a custom modal Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm creating a custom modal pop-up in the product page, in which I need to put product attributes.

I have included "product-variants.tpl" to my custom tpl and the attributes display properly in the modal.

But when the attributes are changed through the modal, they jump back to the values chosen in the product page. I need the modal to be able to change the attributes as

---

UPDATE:

I noticed that when an attribute is chosen in the product page, it changes the URL in the address bar, but when an attribute is changed through the modal, the URL is not updated. I tried enabling force update of friendly URL, but it did not help.

---

UPDATE 2:

```
{block name="content"}
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="position: absolute;
top: 385px;
left: 345px;">
    Inquiry
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                {if isset($product)}
                    <h5 class="modal-title" name="mysubject">Inquire about {$product.name} </h5>
                    {/if}


                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="" class="form-control" required>
                        <label for="recipient-mail" class="col-form-label">E-mail:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="customer_mail" value="" class="form-control" required>
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Phone:</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="customer_phone" value="" class="form-control" required>
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Free text:</label>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-9"  style="float:none;">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="customer_message" placeholder="How can we help?" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl'}
                        {block name='product_prices'}
                            {include file='catalog/_partials/product-prices.tpl'}
                        {/block}

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Отказ</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button_pressed">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

{/block}

This is the .tpl that I use - literally includes the product attribute tpl file in mine

Comment: Hi, the address bar update is performed dynamically via Javascript (not related to friendly URLs). Also, you might want to post your code as well as some screenshots and/or a short screencast to make it easier for others to assist you.

Comment: @BrunoLeveque have posted the tpl code for the modal, that I use.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out, that I need to copy the product-attributes code and delete the class name of the main div

```
<div class="product-variants">
```

to:

`<div class="">`

and then the attributes stay the chosen ones in the modal.